# Using Nested For loop for Printing the following pattern

Tags: generics

I am just a beginner in C language programming. Could you please tell me how to print the pattern 100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 using a Nested for loop in C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nested For Loop as asked in the question

```js
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int i =0;
  int j =0;

  for(i =100; i>0; i--){
    for(j=i; j%10==0 ; j--){
        printf("%d \t", j);
    }
  }
}
```

The Nested for loop (For loop inside a for loop) will increase the time complexity(will consume more time), the below code maybe helpful and it is simple!

```js
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
  int i=0;

  for(i=100; i>0; i-=10){
    printf("%d \t", i);
  }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this definitely helped..but Idid require a nested for loop for the sake of the question asked :D , Could you please help?